# Sonar update failure [ Default value must not be set on parameter 'api/views/projects?pageSize' as it's marked as required]

Tags: java, sonarqube, updates

During sonar update from 5.0 to 5.1 I got following error

> Migration failed: Default value must not be set on parameter
>   'api/views/projects?pageSize' as it's marked as required . Please
>   check logs.

Update process was started from http://localhost:9000/setup
I followed update guide on http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading

How to resolve that error and proceed with update?

**EDIT:**

I am migrating from embeded H2 database to postgress, so I do not mind loosing all data in database. I droped and created database from scratch.
Sonar started, created tables in database, but web UI is not accesible. I am getting the very same error- this time displayed directly in browser.

I also removed most of */opt/sonar/extensions/plugins* leaving only

sonar-build-breaker-plugin-1.1.jar
   sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.2.jar
   sonar-java-plugin-3.1.jar
   sonar-jira-plugin-1.2.jar
   sonar-views-plugin-2.7.jar

But error still persist.

Logs:

```
2015.04.08 11:39:31 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database                                                                     
Default value must not be set on parameter 'api/views/projects?pageSize' as it's marked as required                                              
    org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService$Param.<init>(WebService.java:601)                                                                     
    org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService$Action.<init>(WebService.java:398)                                                                    
    org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService$Action.<init>(WebService.java:374)                                                                    
    org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService$Controller.<init>(WebService.java:206)                                                                
    org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService$Controller.<init>(WebService.java:192)                                                                
    org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService$Context.register(WebService.java:126)                                                                 
    org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService$Context.access$300(WebService.java:105)                                                               
    org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService$NewController.done(WebService.java:161)                                                               
    com.sonar.views.A.L.define(Unknown Source)                                                                                               
    org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.<init>(WebServiceEngine.java:55)                                                                    
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)                                                                    
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)                                             
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)                                     
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)                                                                          
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)                                                      
    org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)                                                      
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)                         
    org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)                                       
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)             
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)                                              
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)                                                                  
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1033)                                 
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1025)                                             
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)                                                     
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)                                                              
    org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)                                                    
    org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.startLevel4Components(ServerComponents.java:821)                                              
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:120)                                                             
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81)                                                                             
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                              
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                            
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                    
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)                                                                                         
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)                                                  
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)                                                                       
    org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)                                                        
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)                                                        
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)                                                                
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)                                                                             
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)                                                                                
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)                                                                                     
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)                                                              
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)                                                    
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)                                                            
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)                                                        
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)                                                                
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)                                                                             
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)                                                                                
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)                                                                                     
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)                                                                                
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)                                                                                  
    org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)                                                                                     
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)                                                                                
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)                                                              
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)                                                              
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)                                                                      
    org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)                                                                                      
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)                                                                                             
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)                                                                                               
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228)                                                                                               
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97)                                                                        
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Views plugin is the culprit. With 5.1, you have to install Views 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

Issues was resolved by deleting *all* plugins from */opt/sonar/extensions/plugins* directory, then reinstaling them one-by-one from update center (http://localhost/updatecenter/available).